# How to revert/reset/undo a locally modified file to a previously staged but not committed state?

Tags: git, undo

I changed a file, then did `git add` it, and then made more changes. Then realized that the staged changes were OK, but the most recent ones weren't. Since I didn't commit yet there is no branch to checkout. So how do I revert/reset/undo the edits up to the staged state?

Comment: @Amadan, I'm not sure from the description. Suppose number.txt had a single character "1". I changed it to "2" and did `git add` for future commit, but didn't commit it yet. Then I changed the character in the file to "3". What do I do to return to "2" but not "1"? If I do `git restore` will the content of the file change to "2" or to "1"?

Comment: @Amadan, it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. change a file.
2. git add without commit
3. change the file again.

use "git restore "  to revert to status after step2